# Crossplatform programming language 2D/3D?

Tags: windows, linux, 3d, cross-platform, 2d

I'm searching for a 2D or 3D programming language (thats working with both Linux and Windows). I've tried Tao Framework, and GTK+ openGL, but both doesn't have many examples.
Anyone know one ??

Comment: What is a 2D or 3D programming language? GTK+ and OpenGL are libraries for C or C++. Is that what you need? For an actual language, take a look at Processing.

Comment: Well, what I technically mean, is any thing you type on the keyboard, and make a 2D or 3D game with. May it be library, programming language, whatever, and it should be crossplatform, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the commercial AAA games you can see are coded in C/C++, using OpenGL or DirectX to render to screen. Note that DirectX only works on Windows (and Xbox). However, to get started, I’d recommend something easier such as the [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/).

There’s heated debate about Java being suitable for games, and I won’t get into it: as this language is often deemed easier than C++ to grasp, you might want to give it a try, along with [JavaGL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javagl/) if you are into oriented object programmation.